# How to make a higher order function for conflict responses c#

Tags: c#, higher-order-functions

I have this function that updates a CouchDB Database but I want it to try updating again if the Response Code is conflict, i want it to have 3 tries, how do I do that?

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UpdateRecord(Profile latestProfile)
    {
        ProfileRecordByUpn profileRecord = await this.GetProfileByUpn(latestProfile);
        Profile oldProfile = profileRecord.Rows.First().Value;

        var client = this.clientFactory.CreateClient(NamedHttpClients.COUCHDB);

        var formatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
        formatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
        };

        var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
        query["rev"] = oldProfile.Rev;

        //Setting the profile Active = true, because as of now we don't have any UI for disabling the account
        latestProfile.Active = oldProfile.Active;

        DateTimeOffset now = DateTimeOffset.Now;
        latestProfile.Created = oldProfile.Created;
        latestProfile.Modified = now;

        //This will check if we the InApp boolean value changed then will set date to Enabled/Disabled
        if (oldProfile.InApp != latestProfile.InApp)
        {                
            if (latestProfile.InApp == true)
            {
                latestProfile.InAppEnabled = now;
                latestProfile.InAppDisabled = oldProfile.InAppDisabled;
            }
            else
            {
                latestProfile.InAppDisabled = now;
                latestProfile.InAppEnabled = oldProfile.InAppEnabled;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            latestProfile.InAppEnabled = oldProfile.InAppEnabled;
            latestProfile.InAppDisabled = oldProfile.InAppDisabled;
        }

        //This will check if we the SMS boolean value changed then will set date to Enabled/Disabled
        if (oldProfile.SMS != latestProfile.SMS)
        {
            if (latestProfile.SMS == true)
            {
                latestProfile.SMSEnabled = now;
                latestProfile.SMSDisabled = oldProfile.SMSDisabled;
            }
            else
            {
                latestProfile.SMSDisabled = now;
                latestProfile.SMSEnabled = oldProfile.SMSEnabled;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            latestProfile.SMSEnabled = oldProfile.SMSEnabled;
            latestProfile.SMSDisabled = oldProfile.SMSDisabled;
        }

        //This will check if we the SMS boolean value changed then will set date to Enabled/Disabled
        if (oldProfile.Email != latestProfile.Email)
        {
            if (latestProfile.Email == true)
            {
                latestProfile.EmailEnabled = now;
                latestProfile.EmailDisabled = oldProfile.EmailDisabled;
            }
            else
            {
                latestProfile.EmailDisabled = now;
                latestProfile.EmailEnabled = oldProfile.EmailEnabled;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            latestProfile.EmailEnabled = oldProfile.EmailEnabled;
            latestProfile.EmailDisabled = oldProfile.EmailDisabled;
        }

        var response = await this.couchDbClient.AuthenticatedQuery(async (c) => {
            return await c.PutAsync($"{API_PROFILES_DB}/{oldProfile.Id.ToString()}?{query}", latestProfile, formatter);
        }, NamedHttpClients.COUCHDB, client);            

        return response;
    }
```

so I will be calling this function from another function? Do I make an another function which is a higher order function and pass this function as a parameter to that higher order function?

Comment: yes, create a new function for the retry logic and call this function from that wrapper function.

Comment: a new function which is a higher order function? is that correct?

Comment: yes, you can make a generic higher order function to take a function of TInput and TOutput and an int value for retry count, and use it wherever you need retry logic.

Comment: can you make an example for that based on my code? because I dont understand it...

Comment: Take a look at [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#step-2--specify-how-the-policy-should-handle-those-faults).

Answer (score 2):

Higher-order functions in C# are implemented by methods taking delegates as parameters, usually an `Action` or `Func` delegate.

In this case, you should use an established library like [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly).

```
var policy = Policy
  .HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Conflict)
  .RetryAsync(3);

var result = await policy.ExecuteAsync(() => UpdateRecord(latestProfile));
```

**Update** to do it yourself (uncompiled and untested code):

```
async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MyRetry(Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> action)
{
  for (int retries = 0; retries < 3; ++retries)
  {
    var result = await action();
    if (result.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Conflict)
      return result;
  }
  return await action();
}
```

The above code will retry 3 times, for 4 total calls if it keeps returning `Conflict`.

Comment: can I do this without using the library Polly? @Stephen Cleary

Comment: Yes; you'd write a method taking a `Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>` delegate and have it contain the retry logic.